How to verify a custom metadata type relationship field's datatype
I have a CMDT SObject called MyCmdt__mdt
It has two fields



Field Name
Field Type




SObjectType__c
Metadata Relationship (Entity Definition)


SObjectField__c
Metadata Relationship (Field Definition)



I want a validation rule that ensures that the value of SObjectField__c is a Checkbox field
My VR looks like this:
NOT(ISBLANK(SObjectField__c)) &&
SObjectField__r.DataType <> 'Checkbox'

But this does not work, the VR always fires even when I choose a Checkbox field.
The documentation of FieldDefinition states

Data type of the field, for example Text(40) or Date/Time. The values are defined as they are in the user interface, not the corresponding API data type names. Available in Tooling API starting version 34.0.

I can see by doing SOQL on CMDT that the value that comes back for the SObjectField__r.DataType is in fact Checkbox

This Custom MetadataTypes and Validation Rules doc is silent on an example of using the FieldDefinition.DataType in a VR within a CMDT SObject.
This Q&A suggests stuff gets wonky in an undocumented way

So, how do I resolve this?

The answer appears undocumented but perhaps someone else can find the relevant documentation.
For CMDT validation rules that inspect Metadata Relationship (FieldDefinition) DataType values, you have to use the Apex primitive type, not what the FieldDefinition doc says (or for that matter what SOQL returns)
So, the correct VR (that works) is:
NOT(ISBLANK(SObjectField__c)) &&
SObjectField__r.DataType <> 'Boolean'

Emboldened, I went to see about other values of DataType in CMDT VR rules



Data type in UX
Value needed in VR
Notes




Number(18, 0)
I have no idea
I tried Decimal, Number(18, 0), Number(18,0), Decimal(18, 0); however CONTAINS(SObjectField__r.DataType,'Decimal') does work


Date/Time
Date/Time
1:1 with UX value


Date
Date
1:1 with UX value


Text(255)
I have no idea
I tried Text(255), String, Text to no avail; however CONTAINS(SObjectField__r.DataType,'String') does work


Picklist
No idea
However, like Text(xx), CONTAINS(SObjectField__r.DataType,'String') does work


Checkbox
Boolean
use Apex primitive type



My conclusion is you need to use the Apex Primitive type if it has no variability (Boolean, Date, DateTime) and

the CONTAINS function (match on String) for Picklists, Text (xx), Text Area, Text Area (long), Rich Text
the CONTAINS function (match on Decimal) for Numbers

I did not explore lookup fields (presumably Id)
I welcome other contributions to making this more definitive
